# Wordpress Custom Field - CSS within Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, custom-fields

How do I use Wordpress Custom Field to specify content alignment?

I have in the header:

```
$pagealign = get_post_meta($id, 'pagealign', false);
if (!empty($pagealign) && is_single())
 {
   if ($pagealign=="center")
     {
       //how to specify css for #pagecontent within php
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend setting the result as a variable 
share [g+] share [fb] share [tw]

How do I use Wordpress Custom Field to specify content alignment?

I have in the header:

```
$pagealign = get_post_meta($id, 'pagealign', false);
if (!empty($pagealign) && is_single())
 {
   if ($pagealign=="center")
     {
       $align = $pagealign
     }
  }
```

Then depending on what exactly you mean by align you can use that variable to define it using inline css...

so Im just guessing text-align

```
<div id='somediv' style='text-align:<?php echo $pagealign?>;'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got what the problem was:
get_post_meta should end with TRUE instead of FALSE

```
$pagealign = get_post_meta($id, 'pagealign', true);
     if (!empty($pagealign) && is_single())
    {
    if ($pagealign=="center") echo '<style type="text/css">#page-wrap {left:0px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;position:relative;}</style>' ;
    if ($pagealign=="right") echo '<style type="text/css">#page-wrap {left:auto;right:30px;}</style>' ;
    }
```